# Blank filling :EL cambio climático puede ( suponer/ significar) un riesgo ¿Cuál verbo es correcto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, expresiones, sinónimos

I think the best answer is significar. It really makes sense.But the correct answer is suponer.It's very confusing.

Comment: Obviously, only a person can suspect something.

Comment: Correct answer given by whom and where?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like:

- Algo que pueda(subjunctive) suponer/significar un riesgo.
- Esto puede(indicative) suponer/significar un riesgo.
- Se sospecha(indicative) que puede/pueda haber un riesgo.

The choice of mood depends on the speaker's degree of uncertainty. "Algo" is somewhat uncertain, so it should be accompanied by "pueda" because the subjunctive is necessary in these cases.

> suponer: 1. tr. Considerar como cierto o real algo a partir de los indicios que se tienen

"Sospechar" is about having an idea without any proof, but this is what one person does, so it cannot be in the subordinate clause, but "suponer" in this particular case is something that may imply something else.

- **Algo** pueda <s>sospechar</s> un riesgo.
- Se(**alguien**) sospecha que..

As defined by [this](https://dle.rae.es/significar), the only right choice is(blank filling):

- ..que **algo** pueda **suponer** un riesgo.

However, "significar" is also widely used.

Comment: So，Can I understand it this way that ”significar“ is more affirmatory than “suponer“？

Comment: I suppose it could be interpreted that way.

Comment: The question is about word choice, not verb forms.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto es utilizar el verbo "*suponer*", ya que al utilizar este verbo, en el contexto de la frase, se entiende que "*suponer*" tiene un sentido de carga ó de arrastre de una serie de circunstancias impredecibles que ya se tienen en cuenta y que "advierte" de algo que "puede" ocurrir si aquellas se dan, por ello, conjuntamente se utiliza el verbo "poder" en sentido de probabilidad junto con el de suponer. Considera una cosa cierta o real para desarrollar el razonamiento.

- El cambio climático "*puede suponer*" -  estas  advirtiendo de las probabilidades probabilidades de seguir con esa conducta o razón principal.

Por el contrario "Significar" es un verbo irregular y pronominal. Es un verbo extraño para utilizarlo en ese tipo de oraciones y lo que hace es una declaración o manifestación de algo de forma más asertiva.

- El cambio climático en sí ya es un riesgo y tiene su propia importancia, si tu dices "*puede significar*", mezclas la probabilidad del verbo "poder" con algo que ya es una declaración importante por si sola. Y eso no es correcto.

Significar: *Dicho de una cosa : Ser , por naturaleza , imitación o convenio , representación , indicio o signo de otra cosa distinta. Dar a entender o hacer saber. Tener este o el otro sentido. Intimar. Ser expresión o signo de una idea, de un pensamiento o de algo material. Hacer saber, declarar o manifestar algo. Representar, valer, tener importancia. Hacerse notar o distinguirse por alguna cualidad.*

Espero que te haya servido.

Diego M.